# How to check if an element exists in a Python array (Equivalent of PHP in_array)?

Tags: python, arrays, lookup

I'm new to Python and I'm looking for a standard function that would tell me if an element is present in an array. I found the `index` method but it throws an exception if the element is not found. I just need some simple function that would return `true` if the element is in the array or `false` if not.

Basically an equivalent to PHP `in_array`.

Comment: You don't even need a function, you just say `if "hello" in some_array: # do stuff!` Way simpler if you ask me.

Comment: Be sure to always check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/), they usually have everything you need.

Comment: I'm sure the docs have everything. But the problem is, when the keyword is just "in", you already need to know where to look for in the doc.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
>>> 1 in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
True
```